# Basic error with accessing JSON data (JS functionality)

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

**Background:**

I'm trying the simple web push notifications example given in Google's documentation of the same (link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user)

I keep running into a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data` error, which means I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I'm a JS neophyte, can you help?

---

My simple function to subscribe user to push is simply:

```
function subscribeUserToPush() {

  const pub_key = document.getElementById("notif_pub_key");
  const service_worker_location = document.getElementById("sw_loc");
  return navigator.serviceWorker.register(service_worker_location.value)
  .then(function(registration) {
    const subscribeOptions = {
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(pub_key.value)
    };
    return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
  })
  .then(function(pushSubscription) {
    sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(pushSubscription);
    return pushSubscription;
  });
}
```

And sendSubscriptionToBackEnd() essentially uses `fetch` like so:

```
function sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscription) {
  const sub_obj =  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'CSRFToken':get_cookie('csrftoken')
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
  }
  return fetch('/subscription/save/', sub_obj)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Bad status code from server.');
    }

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(responseData) {
    if (!(responseData.data && responseData.data.success)) {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server.');
    }
  });
}
```

This fails with the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Doing `console.log(sub_obj)` shows this object:

```
Object { method: "POST", headers: {…}, body: "{\"endpoint\":\"https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABcaErG3Zn6Urzn5Hfhpyjl0eJg_IVtcgZI-sQr5KGE0WEWt9mKjYb7YXU60wgJtj9gYusApIJnObN0Vvm7oJFRXhbehxtSFxqHLOhSt9MvbIg0tQancpNAcSZ3fWA89E-W6hu0x4dqzqnxqP9KeQ42MYZnelO_IK7Ao1cWlJ41w8wZSlc\",\"keys\":{\"auth\":\"AJfXcUMO3ciEZL1DdD2AbA\",\"p256dh\":\"BN84oKD3-vFqlJnLU4IY7qgmPeSG96un-DttKZnSJhrFMWwLrH2j1a0tTB_QLoq5oLCAQql6hLDJ1W4hgnFQQUs\"}}" }
```

Also doing `console.log(response);` right before `return response.json();` displays:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/subscription/save/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

---

Changing `return response.json()` to `return response.text()` and then doing a console log on `responseData` gives the entire HTML of the page. I end up with the error `Error: Bad response from server.`

Comment: Try doing `return response.text()` instead, then log the `responseData` - sounds like it's not giving you JSON

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` *after* `response.json()` give?

Comment: @JackBashford It doesn't get past `.json()` currently, because deserialization fails and an error is thrown

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Added the results of your suggestion at the end of the question

Comment: Thanks, so `/subscription/save/` is sending you HTML instead of JSON - sounds like you should look at the (backend) code handling `/subscription/save/`

Comment: @CertainPerformance: your clue led me to solve the problem. See the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was that `CSRFToken` was mislabeled when being set in `sendSubscriptionToBackEnd`. It should have been `X-CSRFToken`. I.e.

```
function sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscription) {
  const sub_obj =  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken':get_cookie('csrftoken'),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
  }
  return fetch('/subscription/save/', sub_obj)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Bad status code from server.');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(responseData) {
    // response from the server
    console.log(responseData)
    if (!(responseData.data && responseData.data.success)) {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server.');
    }
  });
}
```

So why was this leading to `return response.json();` failing?

Because the project in question routes requests that fail csrf checks to a default view - one which doesn't return a json response at all. Mystery solved!